# Count the amount of bigrams in sentences in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks a bit like this:

```
sentences <- c("sample text in sentence 1", "sample text in sentence 2")
id <- c(1,2) 

df <- data.frame(sentences, id)
```

I would like to have a count where I can see the occurrence of certain bigrams. So lets say I have:

```
trigger_bg_1 <- "sample text"
```

I expect the output of 2 (as there are two occurrences of "sample text" in the two sentences. I know how to do a word count like this:

```
trigger_word_sentence <- 0

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  words <- df$sentences[i]
  words = strsplit(words, " ")
  
  for(i in unlist(words)){ 
    if(i == trigger_word_sentence){
      trigger_word_sentence = trigger_word_sentence + 1
    }
  }
}
```

But I cant get something working for a bigram. Any thoughts on how I should change the code to get it working?

But as I have a long test of trigger-words which I need to count in over

Comment: Maybe `length(grep(trigger_bg_1, sentences, fixed = TRUE))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to count the sentences where you have a match you can use `grep`:

```
length(grep(trigger_bg_1, sentences, fixed = TRUE))
#[1] 2
```

In case you want to count how many times you find `trigger_bg_1` you can use `gregexpr`:

```
sum(unlist(lapply(gregexpr(trigger_bg_1, sentences, fixed = TRUE)
 , function(x) sum(x>0))))
#[1] 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `sum` a `grepl`

```
sum(grepl(trigger_bg_1, df$sentences))
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are really interested in **bigrams** rather than just set word combinations, the package `quanteda` can offer a more substantial and systematic way forward:

Data:

```
sentences <- c("sample text in sentence 1", "sample text in sentence 2")
id <- c(1,2) 
df <- data.frame(sentences, id)
```

Solution:

```
library(quanteda)
# strip sentences down to words (removing punctuation):
words <- tokens(sentences, remove_punct = TRUE)
# make bigrams, tabulate them and sort them in decreasing order:
bigrams <- sort(table(unlist(as.character(tokens_ngrams(words, n = 2, concatenator = " ")))), decreasing = T)
```

Result:

```
bigrams
in sentence sample text     text in  sentence 1  sentence 2 
          2           2           2           1           1
```

If you want to inspect the frequency count of a specific bigram:

```
bigrams["in sentence"]
in sentence 
          2
```